# VBA Printing Text in one Cell with multiple Colors

Tags: excel, vba

I want to print some text in one cell with multiple colors:

```
Sheet1.Cells(1,1) = "Standard Text in Black" & Sheet2.Cells(1,1)
```

I would like the item in sheet 2 to stand out and be a different color is there anyway of doing that, that's still in the same cell?

Comment: My tip ... start recording a macro, change the format of the cell to what you want, end the recording and then review the created code.  You can then adapt that to your own project.

Comment: [this may prove useful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Font.Color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken to get what you mean, maybe something like this ?

```
Sub test()
Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Standard Text in Black"
CharLen1 = Len(Sheet1.Cells(1, 1))
CharLen2 = Len(Sheet2.Cells(1, 1))
Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) & " " & Sheet2.Cells(1, 1)
Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Characters(Start:=CharLen1 + 2, Length:=CharLen2).Font.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```

For a simple explanation :
Assumed that your Sheet1 cell A1 has a word : "hello"
And Sheet2 cell A1 has a sentence : "how are you"

The total character in "hello" is 5 character (CharLen1).
The total character in "how are you" is 11 character (CharLen2).

After "hello", added with a space - then the highlight will start on the 7th character (Start:=Charlen1+2) for as many characters exist in Sheet2 cell A1 (Length:=CharLen2). In this "how are you" case, the highlight length will be 11 characters (CharLen2).

Comment: Glad I can help